# how to use 'import' in vue.js cdn?

Tags: vue.js

How to import '.vue' file in cdn?

I tried import ".vue" in "ASP.NET Framework MVC + vue.js cdn"

```html
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="https://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="example">
                <my-component></my-component>
                <my-component></my-component>
                <my-component></my-component>
                <my-component2></my-component2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Child = {
            template: '<div>This is a user-defined component!</div>'
        }

        new Vue({
            el: '#example',
            // ...
            components: {
                'my-component': () => import('Test.vue'),// This is problem
                'my-component2': Child//It worked
            }
        })
    </script>
```

I got the below error:

> vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: () =>
>   import('Test.vue') Reason: TypeError: Failed to resolve module
>   specifier 'Test.vue'

Comment: `import()` has [patchy browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import) though it is provided by [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1) (see also the [_Loader_](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) spec). To load a single-file Vue component, you also need the [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) which again, is Webpack specific. In short, you cannot do this (yet) directly in your browser

Comment: You can dynamically import Vue components, just not in the typical single-file `.vue` format. See https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-js-single-file-javascript-components-in-the-browser-c03a0a1f13b8